# Deleting local source of Git Repository

Tags: git, git-push

Completely new to Git. Just created a local repository in Windows using the command prompt (`git pull/push origin master`) and successfully pushed it to my repository on github.com.

Can I now delete this folder locally without consequences? Or have I created a link between these two locations that shouldn´t be messed with?

Comment: Note that git and github are different things. Your question is about git, not github.

Comment: If you have pushed to Github, then you're free to delete the local folder without any consequences, but you might want keep it to your local work space in case you want to do any changes, otherwise, you need to clone it from Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to **push** everything in the online `repo`. (If you want to be sure that the push has been succesfully, take a look.. just in case who knows)

> 1. git commit -m 'message'  //You will have to do a commit (after adding files)
> 2. git push TestProject master  //You cannot associate a message to the push

Then you can completely delete it, since it's safe online. And you can re-download again when it's wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete it like any other folder.

All local changes remain local until you do `git push`

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your local repository safely.

it **WILL NOT** affect your remote repository.

If for some reason you need to make changes in the branch, you can simply pull it down again.